# redux Array in state got undefined after reducer finish

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux

I'm working on a project that use react-redux for front side.
and there is a problem I already solve, but I can't figure it out why.
can someone give me the idea?

problem is, 
I init my "guidelineManagement" state below(it's in guidelineManagement.js):

```
    const init = {
      page: 'GuidelineTableComponent',
      status: null,
      msg: [],
      error: null,
      guidelineData: [],
      data: []
    }
```

and I have another reducer handling login status,
it in 'login.js'.
I use `combineReducers` to combine two reducer.

now, In every page loading, I'll do an action "fetchLoginStatus",
it load login status from server, and reducer handle in `login.js`,

so, in `guidelineManagement` reducer, it will perform default case.

my perform look like this

```
default:
  console.log({...state})
  return {...state}
```

but when I check the logger after "fetchLoginStatus" finish,
the state become below:

before `fetchLoginStatus`:

```
guidelineManagement:
    data: Array []
    error: null
    guidelineData: Array []
    msg: Array []
    page: "GuidelineTableComponent"
    status: null
    <prototype>: Object { … }
```

but after `fetchLoginStatus` finish:

```
guidelineManagement: 
    data: Array []
    error: null
    guidelineData: Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]
    msg: undefined
    page: "GuidelineTableComponent"
    status: "success"
    <prototype>: Object { … }
```

guidelineManagement.msg become undefined.

and if I change my default case to below, it'll work fine

```
default:
  console.log({...state})
  return state
```

the result after `fetchLoginStatus` action become:

```
guidelineManagement: 
    data: Array []
    error: null
    guidelineData: Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]
    msg: Array []
    page: "GuidelineInsertComponent" ​​
    status: "success"
    <prototype>: Object { … }
​
```

the result is right, msg remain empty array.

btw, `console.log` in default case says that in use case block, 
`msg` is empty array, means that before return, msg is correct.

by the way, in login state, there is a msg array too,
in my design, state.msg use to receive server response.

and I've notice that only msg cause this problem.
state.guidelineManagement.data and state.guidelineManagement.guidelineData
both are array too, and they remain the same state before action finish.

any idea what cause this problem?

Comment: by the way, guidelineData update before and after `checkLoginStatus` action is because that I've call other action to do ajax call. and after ajax finish, the reducer handle AJAX_COMPLETE action won't affect msg

Comment: I use thunkmiddleware to wrap the ajax call

Comment: You should NOT do `return {...state}` in the default case, this will unnecessarily make lots of components re-render even if there is no change. Return the unmodified state object. Please post what you are doing in the relevant reducer actions and remove the extra lines from your code snippets to make it easier to read.

Comment: @Dominic ok, thanks, i just notice this different when i try to solve this bug...

Answer (score 1):

OK, after hours of searching and debugging,
I figure it out,

it's not about `return {...state}`, `return state`
nor about many msg in different reducer (`login` and `guidelineManagement`)

it's just a small mistake when I create an action for handling ajax data, and notify react to rerender the page:

```
export const refreshGuideline = (status, data, msg) => ({
  type:types.GUIDELINE_REFRESH_GUIDELINE_DATA,
  status,
  data
})
```

and in reducer:

```
    case types.GUIDELINE_REFRESH_GUIDELINE_DATA:
      state.guidelineData = action.data
      state.status = action.status
      state.msg = action.msg
      return {...state}
```

action.msg is undefined, so state.guidelineManagement.msg change to undefined...

after change action below, everything work fine.

```
export const refreshGuideline = (status, data, msg) => ({
  type:types.GUIDELINE_REFRESH_GUIDELINE_DATA,
  status,
  data,
  msg
})
```

oh, and the reason why logger log before and after `fetchLoginStatus` action, guidelineManagement.msg is different even if fetchLoginStatus didn't change `msg`, is just because that `refreshGuideline` is invoke after an ajax call, and it's asynchronous.....

I just spend all the day search and experience how object assignment and array assignment working...